# NSManagedObject dynamic attribute update in willSave or validateForUpdate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmanagedobject

I have an NSManagedObject that has an attribute that I use only for ordering in an NSFetchedResultsController. The value of that attribute is determined from the values of other attributes or relationships.

Therefore I figure out its value when I am getting ready to save the object. It seems, from my reading of documentation and experimenting, that I can do this in either `- (void) willSave` or `- (BOOL) validateForUpdate: NSError **error`.

My experimenting shows me these are called in tandem, first `validateForUpdate` then `willSave`.

However, since my insight into what is happening behind the scenes is poor, I was wondering it anyone could advise if one place is better than the other to set the value and why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a derived value, you typically do not want to save it, but if you do want to save it (thus negating the advantage of dynamically generating it, but can be done for speed reasons if you have a lot of objects and want to do some fancy predicate work.) you can set it up in your model as a normal value then make a custom accessor that checks to see if the primitive value is set, with `primitiveValueForKey:@"propertyName"`... something like

```
.h 
@property()NSString* someProperty;

.m
@dynamic someProperty;
-(NSString *) someProperty
{
    pValue = [self primitiveValueForKey;@"someProperty"];
    if(!pValue)
    {
         //calculate pvalue
         pValue = [self derivedPValue];
         [self setPrimitiveValue: pValue forKey:@"someProperty"];
    }
 return pValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grady. I completely agree and did not want to store it. I tried to get a transient attribute to work, but I could not get the sorting to work since the value was not in the SQL store and the sorting seems to be done in SQLite.

Comment: if you don't want to store it then just define a getter, and derive the value in there, all of your kv code should work just fine, but you wont be able to get advantages from the database...

Comment: That's what I thought but with setting my sort descriptors array with a sort descriptor like `[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"sortPosition" ascending: NO]` I get a crash for uncaught exception with the reason: **'keypath sortPosition not found in entity <NSSQLEntity TravelSegment id=16>'** This is with `TravelSegment` being a subclass of `NSManagedObject` auto generated by Xcode and defining `sortPosition` in a category as `@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger sortPosition;` with an appropriate method to return an NSInteger.

Comment: OK, I tried this and ran into the following problem: the entity data are fetched in an order in the persistent store (since it seems the sort descriptor is translated and applied to the SQL SELECT statement) but the section header is generated from the object properties. With this custom getter the property value may end up different from what is in the database and the object ends up in the wrong section -- crash with message **The fetched object at index 2776 has an out of order section name**

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to be in `willSave`; you're not technically doing validation, and the [discussion for the method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-BBCGBABB) makes reference to computing derived values.

Comment: That makes sense. If I make a change in the object but don't save the `NSManagedObjectContext` is it possible that by using `willSave` that my derived value will not get updated and my display may get out of sync with the current values?

Comment: Yes, definitely. You may be better off going with the derived attribute approach suggested by @GradyPlayer above.